# C# Lock Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am currently trying to do some reading for locking for threads in C#
.

If I have a class similar to below

```
public class Connection
{
    bool Connected;
    internal bool startConnection(Device dev)
    {
       // start connection
       Connected = true;
    }

    internal bool endConnection(Device dev)
    {
       // End connection
       Connected = false;
    }

    private void readFromConnected(Device dev)
    {
        if(Connected)
        {
            // read values from connected device
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have right now is that i have multiple threads using this class to read values from different devices

A problem arises when a thread tries to read values when it is actually disconnected, but attempts to read the values anyways because another thread has kept the Connected bool to true;

The thread that is calling this class looks like this.

```
Device deviceReceived;
public PollingInstance(Device deviceSent)
    {
        deviceReceived = deviceSent;
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2500); //1000 = 1 sec
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }


 private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        Connection.startConnection(deviceReceived);
        Connection.readFromConnected(deviceReceived);
        Connection.endConnection(deviceReceived);
     }
 }
```

The part of the main class calling Polling Instance looks similar to this

```
foreach(Device dev in listOfDev)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => pollThread(dev));
}
private void pollThread(Device dev)
{
    PollingInstance testingPoll = new PollingInstance(dev);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this imply that you need a `ConcurrentDictionary<Device,bool>` to track the connection status of each device separately?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary its a typo. C# won't let you do that.

Comment: Yea what i meant to write was if(Connected) but my head was in the clouds at that moment

Comment: Are there multiple Devices that should be usable independently?

Comment: Mind me asking what you are building?  What are these devices?

Comment: These devices are independent from one another, the Device is a device object that has information about how the connection should be set up, and what to read.

Comment: Can you make a method on Device that calls startConnection, readFromConnected, and endConnection? Then you can put a lock around that, using a per-Device-instance object to lock on.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Why is `connected` a `bool`?

Try this.

```
public class Connection
{
    private int _connections = 0;
    internal bool startConnection(Device dev)
    {
       // start connection
       if(Interlocked.Increment(ref _connections) == 1)
       {
          //do work to connect.
       }
    }

    internal bool endConnection(Device dev)
    {
       // End connection
       if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref _connections) == 0)
       {
          //do work to disconnect.
       }
    }

    private void readFromConnected(Device dev)
    {
        if(_connections > 0)
        {
            // read values from connected device
        }
    }
}
```

This will "works" for some values of work. But is prone to connections being left open due to exceptions and sloppy/forgetful programming. Therefore I would advise the following.

```
Device device = ...
using(var connection = device.CreateConnection())
{
    var results = connection.Read();
}

public abstract class Connection : IDisposable
{
    public object Read();
}

public class Device
{
    private class DeviceConnection : Connection 
    {
        private Device Parent { get; set; }

        void Dispose()
        {
            Parent.StopConnection();
        }
        public object Read() 
        {
            return Device.readFromConnected();
        }
    }        

    private int _connections = 0;
    public Connection CreateConnection()
    {
       // start connection
       if(Interlocked.Increment(ref _connections) == 1)
       {
          //do work to connect.
       }
       return new DeviceConnection { Parent = this };
    }

    private bool StopConnection()
    {
       // End connection
       if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref _connections) == 0)
       {
          //do work to disconnect.
       }
    }

    private object readFromConnected()
    {
        //Device is guaranteed to be connected now!
    }
}
```

Comment: If `CreateConnection` is called while another call is in the process of connecting you may end up with a connection that think its connected when it really isn't.  You are also assuming that `readFromConnected` is thread safe which is likely to not be the case if device is really a "device".  That aside using the dispose pattern for this sort of thing is the way to go.

Comment: @Yaur all very good points. But too late in the day for me to correct. Am in bed now.

Comment: thanks for the help guys, all of these replies has given me an idea as how to solve this problem, but requires testing first.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say exactly what will happen, because the code you posted won't even compile.

you wan't something like this:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Connection connection = whereverThisComesFrom();
    if(!Monitor.TryEnter(connection))  return; // another timer is in progress
    try
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         connection.startConnection(deviceReceived);
         connection.readFromConnected(deviceReceived);
         connection.endConnection(deviceReceived);
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      Monitor.Exit(connection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> A problem arises when a thread tries to read values when it is
>   actually disconnected, but attempts to read the values anyways because
>   another thread has kept the Connected bool to true;

Can you use a try/finally to ensure you set the boolean properly?

The `lock` keyword is equivalent to a Monitor try/finally.

```
object syncObject = new object();
Monitor.Enter(syncObject);
try {
    // Code updating shared data
}
finally {
    Monitor.Exit(syncObject);
}

object syncObject = new object();
lock (syncObject) {
// Code updating shared data
}
```

Comment: The point of using `TryEnter` instead of just doing a lock is to prevent a thread leak if the timer fires while the callback is still happening.

Comment: It is possible to do this lock free with a simple count of threads that have initialized/uninited the class. It also places the burden of thread safety in the calling code, where it is most dangerous.